# Custom print preview page with php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I would like to know if there is a way to customize the print preview page. I have a button on my page "Print page" and if I press it, I will get the print preview page. In this page there are some informations of users. I want to verify if the user that clicks this button is logged in and if so, in the print preview page will be only his informations. Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for a print stylesheet/formattings. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#media-types

Answer (score 0):

You can set a [specific print CSS style sheet](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/). This could hide or show some things which should be hidden or only shown on the print output. This "print" style sheet does not affect the normal browser view.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="navigation"><a href="/">HOME</a></div>
<div id="print_copy_right" style="display:none">(c) domain.com</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
@media print {
   #navigation_bar {display:none}
   #print_copy_right {display:block}
}
```